# How to detect changes in wp_editor?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce-4, wp-editor

How do I detect in JavaScript if the content of a `wp_editor` tinyMCE instance has changed in WordPress 4.2.2?

I've tried with `tinyMCE.editors["content"].isDirty()` but the result is always false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (tinyMCE.activeEditor.isDirty())
    alert("You must save your contents.");
```

is working for me.

More: [activeEditor](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:property.tinymce.activeEditor), 
[isDirty](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.isDirty)

Comment: The problem with the "activeEditor" approach is that if you have, like in my case, more than one editor in the post, you don't know which is the "dirty" one.

Comment: You can use this in case you have multiple editors: `tinymce.get(tinyMCEEditorId).isDirty()` where `tinyMCEEditorId` is the WP Editor ID, that is, the second parameter you provide to the `wp_editor` method. Also, for anyone that's trying to use an onChange event of sorts, `isDirty` is the approach recommended by tinyMCE, for performance reasons. https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@onchange_callback/ "We strongly recommend users to utilize the isDirty method to determine if the editor contents were changed..."